# Why does RFC5816 not change the version number defined in RFC3161

Tags: timestamp, rfc

So, RFC5816 https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5816.txt changes the specification of RFC3161 https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3161.txt

RFC3161 specifies the 'version' field in TSTInfo to be set to 1

Why does RFC5816 not change the value of this field? wouldn't that be exactly the idea of this field? If not, how else would a new version need to be defined so that it would make sense to change the value in this version field?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the authors? It's extremely difficult for uninvolved people to judge the intent of someone. Their e-mail addresses are in the RFC so sending them a professionally worded e-mail asking for the rationale behind this should do the trick.

Comment: 5816 changes the _token_ which is the CMS SignedData that _wraps_ TSTInfo, but it doesn't change TSTInfo at all even in the slightest. If the structure of data in TSTInfo was changed it would make sense to change its version.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 that is correct, but according to the specification, the version field "describes the version of the time-stamp token." and the time-stamp token is the wrapping ContentInfo, not the wrapped TSTInfo - and the specification makes restrictions for this ContentInfo